# white-space pre is not working at all | Prism Syntax highlighting

Tags: css, whitespace, prism, line-breaks

I have some pre tags with white-spaces style pre. This style does not work. here is my example:
http://jsfiddle.net/daFalk/8fobx4ck/

F.e. after `<div class="demo-frame">` should be a linebreak now. But it isnt.

Anyone an great idea?

Thanks in advance. 
Best, Falk

EDIT: 
I found the point, but still do not understand how can I achieve this. Here http://jsfiddle.net/daFalk/gd1eu4y7/ we can see two block of codes. The difference between them is, that in the first block there is an linebreak within the code. So it consists of two line code. The second block is just one line of html-code. This makes the difference.

Now I dont have (or dont know how) to influence this output within prism. (Prism is adding this to the DOM). Is there an other way to ad these "breaks" using javascript?

Comment: There is no linebreak in your html code.

Comment: Ok, please see the example here prismjs.com/examples.html look for the line "Attribute without value". Its the same. There are no br-tags of course. I am using prism and it doesnt make the line-breaks. Its not about word-break, its about white-space see here: w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstood `word-break` property. For this puropse I would use rather `<br/>`. Here you have [link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-break.asp) to w3c with more details about `word-break`

Comment: Ok, please see the example here http://prismjs.com/examples.html look for the line "Attribute without value". Its the same. There are no br-tags of course. 
I am using prism and it doesnt make the line-breaks. Its not about word-break, its about white-space see here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp